# Python: Save a tuple in a list

Tags: python, list, dataframe, tuples

From data saved in a DataFrame, I have to re-create the format below (i.e. list(tuple(tuples))), so it should have the same structure as:

```
coord = [((9, 9), (10, 6), (11, 3),(12, 6))]
```

So far I have been able to create the tuples from DataFrame by this code:

```
coord_y = tuple(data_df['data'].iloc[i:])
coord_x = tuple(data_df['data'].index.values[i:])

coord = list(zip(coord_x, coord_y)) # stack into (x,y) coord
```

which yields:

```
[(9, 9), (10, 6), (11, 3), (12, 6)]
```

Which is wrong because it is missing the "outer" tuple and should look like this:

```
[((9, 9), (10, 6), (11, 3),(12, 6))]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `coord = [tuple(zip(coord_x, coord_y))] # stack into (x,y) coord`

Comment: You get a list of tuples of integers because that's what you did with `list(zip(...))`. If you want the result of `zip` to be in a tuple, do `tuple(zip())` and then enclose that in a list with `[...]`

Comment: @GennadyKandaurov Thank you so much Gennady! That worked. If you reply as an answer I'll be happy to accept and upvote it for future reference

Comment: can you show your dataframe? i think is like `df = pd.DataFrame({"data":[9,9,10,6,11,3,12,6]})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tuple()` creates a tuple with all the data instead of a `list()`, and enclosing brackets `[]` create a new list with one element - early created tuple:

```
coord = [tuple(zip(coord_x, coord_y))] # stack into (x,y) coord
```

Answer (score 0):

One of these should do:

```
[(tuple(zip(coord_x, coord_y), ))]
```

or

```
[(*zip(coord_x, coord_y), )]
```

Answer (score -1):

Just wrap your zip in a tuple.

```
coord_y = tuple(data_df['data'].iloc[int(time_steps[-1]-l-1):])
coord_x = tuple(data_df['data'].index.values[int(time_steps[-1]-l-1):])

coord = [tuple(zip(coord_x, coord_y))] # stack into (x,y) coord
```

Comment: Did you try this? It gives the same thing OP already gets because `list(sequence)` just converts the sequence to a list

Comment: That does not work, it becomes: [(9, 9), (10, 6), (11, 3), (12, 6)]

Comment: Sorry yea, i forget that `list()` will convert a iterable to a list, if you wrap it in `[]` it should work. Corrected the code.